# How to generate large no of records in spark

Tags: apache-spark

How to generate large(million) no of records with multiple fields in spark.I don't read data from file but the data will be random generated data.From that data I want to create **RDD**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a place to get help with programming problems. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can take reference from [Random data generation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#random-data-generation) provided by the spark.

`RandomRDDs` provides factory methods to generate random double RDDs or vector RDDs.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs._


val sc: SparkContext = ...

// Generate a random double RDD that contains 1 million i.i.d. values drawn from the
// standard normal distribution `N(0, 1)`, evenly distributed in 10 partitions.
val u = normalRDD(sc, 1000000L, 10)
// Apply a transform to get a random double RDD following `N(1, 4)`.
val v = u.map(x => 1.0 + 2.0 * x)
```